# ILMerge targetplatform to 4.6.2 issue

Tags: c#, dll, ilmerge

I am trying to merge couple of dll's into one dll using ILMerge.exe.
I was able to do that earlier with the targetplatform as "v4".
Now, i am in need to merge 2 dlls' into 1 dll with the targetplatform as "4.6.2" by using the following command.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge>ilmerge /targetplatform:"v4.6.2,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" /log /out:Test.merged.dll myfirst.dll mysecond.dll
```

I am getting the "Platform 'v4.6.2' not recognized." error.
I have installed 4.6.2 framework in my machine.but i dont see the folder structure for 4.6.2 as i see for 4 like "*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319*"

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: "v4.6.2" is a property of the reference assemblies that are used to compile a project.  Not what ILMerge needs, it needs to know the version of the metadata in the final assembly.  There is only one version of the metadata for any 4.x.y assembly, it is "v4".